# What is the recommended port for MQTT over Websocket

Tags: websocket, mqtt

As in the title:

What is the recommended port for MQTT over Websocket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a registered port for MQTT over Websockets as there is for native MQTT.

But as with all Websocket based transports the default ports should probably match http/https (80/443) since these are the underlying transports that are used to bootstrap a Websocket connection. These ports are most likely to be open by default on any firewall (at least for outbound connections) and also the ports likely to be transparently proxied if needed.